# Returning different types of function (out-) parameters

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, return, out

I am trying to write a method that takes a byte array as input and several other types as output variables. The method should be able to check the type of the "output" parameters and read the correct value from the byte array (this part works already).

But I cannot find an easy way to get the output parameters.

This is what I have so far (edited, because of missing comma):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestSuite_flexComDotNet
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {

            UInt16 ui16 = 0x0101;
            Int16 i16 = 0x0202;
            UInt32 ui32 = 0x03030303;
            Int32 i32 = 0x04040404;
            byte[] b = new byte[12];
            for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
            {
                b[i] = (byte)(0x05 + i);
            }
            byte[] buffer;
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.IO.BinaryWriter bw = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(ms);
            bw.Write(ui16);
            bw.Write(i16);
            bw.Write(ui32);
            bw.Write(i32);
            bw.Write(b);
            buffer = ms.GetBuffer();
            Array.Resize(ref buffer, (int)ms.Position);
            Test(buffer, new object[] { ui16, i16, ui32, i32, b });

            ui16 = (UInt16) o[0];
            i16 = (Int16)   o[1];
            ui32 = (UInt32) o[2];
            i32 = (Int32)   o[3];
            b = (byte[])o[4];
    }
    public static Test(byte[] daten, object[] args)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(daten);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (args[i])
            {
                case UInt16 _:
                    args[i] = br.ReadUInt16();
                    break;
                case Int16 _:
                    args[i] = br.ReadInt16();
                    break;
                case UInt32 _:
                    args[i] = br.ReadUInt32();
                    break;
                case Int32 _:
                    args[i] = br.ReadInt32();
                    break;
                case byte[] b:
                    {
                        args[i] = br.ReadBytes(b.Length);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

While inside the `Test` method, the `args`parameter has the correct values, but they naturally never get outside to their corresponding simple vars `ui16`, `i16`,  and so on...

When I change the signature to

```
public static object[] Test(byte[] daten, object[] args);
```

And then `return args;` at the end of the function, I get my values outside of the function, but they are inside the `object[]`, and I still would have to write something like this in `main`:

```
object[] o = Test(buffer, new object[] { ui16, i16, ui32, i32, b });
ui16 = (UInt16) o[0];
i16 = (Int16)   o[1];
ui32 = (UInt32) o[2];
i32 = (Int32)   o[3];
```

passing `args` as  reference parameter would work, but then I would have to declare another variable instead of passing `new object[] { ui16, i16, ui32, i32, b }`

I think, I would need a mixture of params and out:

`public static void Test(byte[] daten, params out ui16, out i16, out ui32);`

but `params` does not work with different types.

Comment: Please, provider more proper code because this one has many syntax errors and while analyzing it's really hard to tell what it is suppose to do. Give us compilible reproductible example.

Comment: Sorry, it seems like some comma  got lost while copying the code, I will edit my question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm your problem is very simple or I don't understand it. The only thing you have to do is to declare your return object earlier and not to create it in function parameter. Just like that:

```
object[] result = new object[] { ui16, i16, ui32, i32, b };
Test(buffer, result);
```

Doing it your way:

```
Test(buffer, new object[] { ui16, i16, ui32, i32, b });
```

you just don't have any chance to get the result values, because this new object is destroyed as soon as Test method ends.
But when you pass it as a reference to earlier created object, everything works as expected.

Comment: Having the result in the object array is only the first step. Because declaring and initialising the variable like you did, does not help in returning the values in my ui16 etc. vars. If i had a chance of declaring a method with a variant number of out vars and of different types, it would be good. See my last code snippet in my question.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. If I pass the result object, as I did, I can read every value from that object. And those values are updated in Test function.

Comment: yes that's right, but I wanted to leave out this extra step. the function signature should be as simple as possible, yet being able to return different parameters and types via the out keyword AND ommiting the read out of the variables from the object array that i have to pass in (and get out again).

Comment: You can always try to implement something like Variant and return this Variant. But it's more work than it's worth.

Comment: It seems like it is the easiest way to pass the variables in as an array of objects and then return another array of objects with the same types but the desired values.,